# No boot menu after installing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I installed windows 7 on my laptop at C:\, and then I installed ubuntu with a bootable usb stick, but when I restart my computer, it boot to windows 7 directly, there is no boot menu to select which os to boot.

what's the problem?

Comment: you didn't install a boot manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which boot manager is your preference, windows or ubuntu.
If you want windows to manage the boot menu, it wouldn't recognize ubuntu directly without a 3rd party boot manager like [easybcd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD).
If you want ubuntu to manager the boot menu, you need to load grub2. [Here's one](http://fitusv.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/fixing-reinstalling-grub-grub2/) of many examples.
If you later change your mind, you can repair your windows boot manager from the windows 7 install disk in repair mode.

Answer (score 1):

[Try re-installing the grub bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2)

.